# Textbook recommendation - looking for a well-written, comprehensive textbook on discrete mathematics for beginners

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

Ideally, the book would be aimed towards Computer Science majors. I would like for the textbook to present the concepts as intuitively as possible, because I want a really strong foundation for discrete math. The books that I'm looking at right now are:

- Applied Discrete Structures by Ken Levasseur
- Discrete Mathematics and its Applications by Kenneth H. Rosen
- Discrete Mathematics with Applications by Susanna Epp

If it's not asking for too much, could you please list the pros and cons of each book for me (disregarding price), or give new recommendations? I have read parts of Rosen already, but I'm looking to purchase a book, so I want to make sure the book I buy is the best one for my situation.

Also, would you recommend any video lectures to supplement the book? I used TheTrevTutor on youtube previously.

Comment: You may also like the book Concrete Mathematics by Graham et al. Its subtitle is "A foundation for computer science", after all.